# SharePoint Online Site Contents stopped working

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I am working on SharePoint Online site collection and suddenly **Site Contents** `_layouts/viewlsts.aspx` stopped working and showing the message

> This page isn’t working - If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 401

I am the site collection administrator on this site, so this is not a permission related issue. Also, checked on multiple browsers and with different users and all are facing the same issue. Also, Console logs are not showing any error messages.

**Scenario** - I just ran a PnP PowerShell command to create lists *(list provisioning)* and after that Site Contents were not working, however the same command I executed few days back and everything was working fine.

My application custom pages / site settings and all the lists & libraries are working fine *(when accessed directly from URL)*, only Site Contents is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the browser cache and open the site in an incognito window to check the result.

Go to Site Content and Structure page as site collection administrator, delete the  provisioned list to compare the result.

```
_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx
```

If the issue still exists, raise a new service request to Microsoft to check if there is something wrong on back-end side.

[image]